# Navigate to view-source: in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I want to save file by open link with IE, but problem is that IE promt for action, i found a way in Firefox to open link as `view-source:` this opens downloading file in browser as binary text and when i can save this text directly and rename extension to zip.

```
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = 0

    url = "view-source:http://mysite/stockquote/NASDAQ/AAPL.zip"
    ie.Navigate url


    state = 0
    Do Until state = 4
        DoEvents
        state = ie.readyState
    Loop


    text = ie.Document.Body.innerHTML ' not worked as file is downloaded before this appears, and prompting for action save or open which i want to avoid it

ie.Document.Write  "<html><head></head><body><div id=""content""></div><script src=""https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js""></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){$.ajax({url: '" & url & "',type: 'get',success: function(data){$('#content').html(data); }});});</script></body></html>"  ' also not work as ajax do not load urk contens
```

1.so how to navigate to view-source: in IE like in firefox?
Sendkeys, XmlHttp and api function for searching windows does not suit me, as i need auth with Csrf token and make everithing without annoing IE windows visible = False.
2. How to download zip file with javascript or ajax without prompting

Comment: Where is the link to actual file location? The normal URL?

Comment: it only available after auth, and this is not matter

Comment: This might help: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/502298-need-help-regarding-ie-automation-using-vba-3.html

Comment: no this not helpful

Comment: Microsoft and Google web browsers do not have a view-source: protocol handler. You need to research https://www.bing.com/search?q=pluggable+protocol+handlers and create your own pluggable protocol extension for IE.

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve CSRF token and authenticate, using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` or `WinHttpRequest.5.1`? Then you may get the content with XHR, and save the response body with `ADODB.Stream` to a file. Can't test that since the URL you provided isn't valid.

Comment: Yes i tryed,  problem is MSXML2.XMLHTTP cant get all cookies from response and cant properly auth to site